# Splitting String numerical values into new columns-Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-presentation

I have a dataframe column having values like this:

```
Salary Offered
----------------------
£18,323 per annum 
£18,000 - £22,000 per annum 
Salary not specified 
£15,000 - £17,000 per annum, pro-rata 
£37,000 - £45,000 per annum 
£9,100 - £9,152 per annum, OTE 
£9.25 - £10.15 per hour 
£35,000 - £40,000 per annum 
£23,000 - £26,600 per annum 
£18,000 - £25,000 per annum, inc benefits
```

So I ran the following command, which did a good job by replacing the pure string values (like: "Salary not specified") with None, which I can replace with random values, but I have to again split them by £:

```
In[13]: df = pd.DataFrame(df.salary_offered.str.split('£',1).tolist(),
                                   columns = ['flips','row'])
In[14]: df['row']
Out[14]: 
0                                     18,323 per annum 
1                           18,000 - £22,000 per annum 
2                                                  None
3                 15,000 - £17,000 per annum, pro-rata 
4                           37,000 - £45,000 per annum 
5                        9,100 - £9,152 per annum, OTE 
6                               9.25 - £10.15 per hour 
7                           35,000 - £40,000 per annum 
8                           23,000 - £26,600 per annum 
9             18,000 - £25,000 per annum, inc benefits
```

Also there are few rows having salaries given in per hour, so will need to replace them as well, which can be done, intuitively. But I want to separate into different columns having the mean values, something like this:

```
Salary (£)
---------------
18323
20000
18000
16000
41000
...
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you can extract what you need (numbers) with a regex, and do your calculations on the result:

```
salaries = (df['Salary Offered']
            .str.replace(',','')
            .str.findall(r'(\d+\.?\d+)')
            .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).astype(float))
            .mean(1))


>>> salaries
0    18323.0
1    20000.0
2        NaN
3    16000.0
4    41000.0
5     9126.0
6        9.7
7    37500.0
8    24800.0
9    21500.0
```

**regex explanation**: `\d` finds any digit character. `\d+` finds any sequence of multiple digits (`+` means one or more in regex). `\.?` means "optionally, find any `.`".

So all together, `\d+\.?\d+` says: "find any sequence of digits, optionally followed by a `.` and another sequence of digits on the other side of that `.`".

**dealing with the `per hour` vs `per annum`**

I'm not sure what you mean to do about the `per hour` rows, but you said that you can do it *intuitively*, so I suppose you have a plan for it.

Personally, I would do something along the lines of the following, though you might have to tweak it based on your dataframe and what you're trying to capture specifically.

```
salaries = (df['Salary Offered']
            .str.replace(',','')
            .str.findall(r'(\d+\.?\d+)')
            .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).astype(float))
            .mean(1)
            .to_frame('salary offered'))

salaries['per'] = df['Salary Offered'].str.extract(r'(per\s\w+)')

>>> salaries
   salary offered        per
0         18323.0  per annum
1         20000.0  per annum
2             NaN        NaN
3         16000.0  per annum
4         41000.0  per annum
5          9126.0  per annum
6             9.7   per hour
7         37500.0  per annum
8         24800.0  per annum
9         21500.0  per annum
```

Comment: can you please explain this line `'(\d+\.?\d+)'` ? How did the  "£" get removed? Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you suggest me any tutorial, or resources where they have clearly explained regular expression coding in python. Thanks

Comment: [regexone](https://regexone.com/) is really good for learning regex in general. Applying them to python is relatively straightforward after that.

Answer (score 2):

***Setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'salary': ['£18,000 - £22,000 per annum', '£9.25 - £10.15 per hour']})
```

Helper function to extract all currency values from a column and return average:

```
def extract_average(s):
    money = list(map(float, re.findall(r'£([\d\.]+)', s)))
    return sum(money)/len(money)
```

**`str.replace`** and **`apply`**:

```
df.salary.str.replace(',', '').apply(extract_average)

0    20000.0
1        9.7
Name: salary, dtype: float64
```